# Mat-Table pagination disabled

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular-material-table

After implementing the server side pagination my `Mat-Table`, the pagination for `Next,Previous,First & Last` is disabled. But the `Items per page` dropdown works well.

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

interface USER {
  id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  reg_date: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-pagination',
  templateUrl: './server-pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-pagination.component.css']
})
export class ServerPaginationComponent {

  ELEMENT_DATA: USER[] = [];
  isLoading = false;
  totalRows = 0;
  pageSize = 5;
  currentPage = 0;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'reg_date'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<USER> = new MatTableDataSource();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
  paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.totalRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Load initial data
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    let URL = `http://localhost/database.php?pageno=${this.currentPage}&per_page=${this.pageSize}`;


    fetch(URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data.rows;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.paginator.pageIndex = this.currentPage;
          this.paginator.length = data.count;
        });
        this.isLoading = false;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    console.log({ event });
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
    this.loadData();
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalRows" [pageIndex]="currentPage" [pageSize]="pageSize" showFirstLastButtons
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" (page)="pageChanged($event)" aria-label="Select page"></mat-paginator>
```

If the `totalRows` was the issue, i even tried to set it to static 2 and still didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think setting paginator to dataSource does not happen after you have some data in dataSource. To try set it again after fetch and might as well move `fetch()` to AfterViewInit as well, then you won't need to play with `setTimeout()`.

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
  paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Load initial data
  }

  loadData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    let URL = `http://localhost/database.php?pageno=${this.currentPage}&per_page=${this.pageSize}`;


    fetch(URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.rows);
          this.paginator.pageIndex = this.currentPage;
          this.paginator.length = data.count;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.totalRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
          this.isLoading = false;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: The problem is `this.dataSource.data=data.rows`. Should be `this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(data.rows)`, and **after** this instruction you use `this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator`;. If you has the table under a "div *ngIf, take account this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168312/undefined-paginator-when-setting-it-to-the-mat-table-data-source/65168666#65168666)