# Is it possible to define paginator if its inside ngIf?

Tags: angular, components, paginator

I have a button and when it is clicked, search and table opens. Its in one component, is it possible to define paginator inside ngIf ?

```
    <div style="text-align: right;" *ngIf="showDokumendiLisaDokiNupp; else dokumendiLisamineContainer">
  <span *ngIf="isDokumendiMuutmineKasutajaleLubatud; else notAllowed"
        class="lisa-nupp"
        (click)="openDokumendiLisamine()">
    + Lisa dokument</span>
  <ng-template #notAllowed>
    <span class="not-allowed"
          matTooltip="Õigus puudub"
          matTooltipPosition="above">+ Lisa dokument</span>
  </ng-template>
</div>

<ng-template #dokumendiLisamineContainer>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: rgb(248, 251, 251);">
```

paginator is here in the footer

```
<mat-paginator
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              [pageSize]="defaultPageSize"
              (page)="onPageChange($event)">
            </mat-paginator>
```

in .ts file i declare it like that:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

it always undefined. inside the if statement

Comment: you can use hidden attribute to hide/show paginator.  Your paginator is still in DOM.

Comment: The answer is yes, but you need "wait" to repaint to asig the paginator to the data source, see, e.g. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168312/undefined-paginator-when-setting-it-to-the-mat-table-data-source/65168666#65168666), but take account also the solution proposed by Alpine

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden attribute in the footer.

The (**ngIf**) conditon does not create an element (**mat-paginator**) in the DOM.

The value of paginator is **undefined** :

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Hidden attribute makes the element invisible but still in the DOM:

```
<div [hidden]="!showDokumendiLisaDokiNupp">
           <mat-paginator
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              [pageSize]="defaultPageSize"
              (page)="onPageChange($event)">
            </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: still undefined. paginator is still under ngIf, so its undefined until the ngIf becomes true ? this hidden doesnt help. i tried to change ngIf to hidden - it works. but then my components doesnt call ngOnDestroy when i click button close and want to hide search and table